# "Naming" template class instantiations

Tags: c++, templates

In my game engine, I've created a pretty funky component-based entity system which allows me to define entity types as a combination of components, specified as template arguments, e.g:

```
typedef Entity<Locateable, Collidable, Renderable /* etc */ > SomeEntity;
```

This works fine, until I need to uniquely identify an instantiation of a template definition..

```
typedef Entity<Locateable, Collidable, Renderable> Missile;
typedef Entity<Locateable, Collidable, Renderable> Bullet;

typeid(Missile) == typeid(Bullet) // sad panda :(
```

Obviously they are they same type, but I'd like them not to be, ideally I'd like to give each a string name, something like this:

```
// Invalid code...
typedef Entity<"Missile", Locateable, Collidable, Renderable> Missile;
typedef Entity<"Bullet", Locateable, Collidable, Renderable> Bullet;
```

That way I could access a static name() method later on. But that doesn't work because the strings need to be statically instantiated. I tried to do this too, but lambdas also aren't allowed...

```
// More invalid code...
typedef Entity<[]()-> char* { return "Missile"; }, Locateable, Collidable, Renderable> Missile;
typedef Entity<[]()-> char* { return "Bullet"; }, Locateable, Collidable, Renderable> Bullet;
```

So, my question is, is there some neat trick that will allow me to name the template definitions inline?

Comment: It feels like this kind of question comes up every so often. Search around this site and you might find some interesting ideas.

Comment: `char_sequence<char...>` may help (with macro to construct it from literal).

Comment: May be better to use inherited classes (preferrably [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)) instead of simple `typedef`'s?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That "funky " typedef Entity might just do that CRTP

Comment: @DieterLücking Of course, that was my intend mentioning it. That would bind `Entity<...,Bullet>` or `Entity<...,Missile>` to the final type. And even a better solution would be. to have `Locateable, Collidable, Renderable` as mixins from the actually deriving class, and have concept checks for these (that would really make a funky, groovin' design).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of just using typedefs, you could use simple inheritance, maybe something like this:

```
class Missile : public Entity<Locateable, Collidable, Renderable>
{
public:
    static std::string name() { return "Missile"; }
};

class Bullet: public Entity<Locateable, Collidable, Renderable>
{
public:
    static std::string name() { return "Bullet"; }
};
```

Comment: In the end I went with this, but defined a macro to make it less boilerplate: `DEFINE_ENTITY("Missile", Locateable, Collideable, Renderable) Missile;' `

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of ECS is to be pointlessly dynamic. If it's not pointlessly dynamic, then why bother using ECS in the first place? Just use regular classes and composition.

Comment: As so often you're so cryptic.

Comment: It's not cryptic. That's brief.